# making calculator with c language

Tags: c

i want to make a calculator and programmed below.

```
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include<stdio.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        char o;
        int x, y;
        while (1)
        {
            printf("type the problem");
            scanf("%d %s %d", &x, &o, &y);
            
            if (o == '+' );
            {
                printf(" %d\n", x + y);
            }
        
            else if (o == '-');
            {
                printf(" %d\n", x - y);
            }
            
            else if (o == '*');
            {
                printf("%d\n", x*y);
            }
        
            else if (o == '/');
            {
                printf("%d\n", x / y);
            }
            
            else
            {
                printf("wrong input! \n");
            }
            
        }
    
    
    
        return 0;
    }
```

this program is not working !
i can't find which part i missed!
for example, if i enter 1 + 3 (one+space+plus+space+three)
this should printf 4 and keep repeat the calculator(not end)
thanks  for reading :)

Comment: `scanf("%d %c %d", &x, &o, &y);` or, better, `if (scanf("%d %c %d", &x, &o, &y) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: And what are you currently experiencing? If you change %s to %c, does that fix your problem?

Comment: Does this code even run?

Comment: thanks for the comments. but still it is not working(can't bulid). maybe the problems are at 'else if' part

Comment: remove extra semicolons

Comment: omg! such a stupid mistake!! big thanks for the comments! Thank you!!!!!111

Comment: and now it works!

Comment: If you type `7/3`, you get `2`, is that what you want? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of tasks `switch ... case` is much better:

```
    int main(void)
    {
        char o;
        int x, y;
        while (1)
        {
            printf("type the problem");
            scanf("%d %c %d", &x, &o, &y);
            
            switch(o)
            {
                case '+':
                    printf(" %d\n", x + y);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    printf(" %d\n", x - y);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if(y == 0) printf("Division by zero!!!!")
                    else printf(" %d\n", x / y);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    printf(" %d\n", x * y);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("wrong input! \n");                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code here. Let's go through it one by one

1. You have used `;` after `if` and `else if` conditions. Remove those unwanted semicolons. Else it will through an error `else without a previous if`
2. You are using `%s` format specifier when you should use `%c`, `%s` is used for strings and `%c` is used for a character.

Comment: thank you!!! now it's working